# Delaying javascript function execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery(Latest release) and have a function called "calculate()" which gets called every time a field is edited and the field exited(blur etc). (To allow "dynamic" calculation")
The calculation takes under 4 seconds to complete, but if the user changes another element on the form before the calculation is complete, then they are queued and the function is called again after the current action is complete.
As I can't stop the function from processing once it's started, is it possible to delay the function by a couple of seconds and then each time a form element is interacted with, add to the timer.

I don't think this is possible, but thoguht i'd give it a shot.

I know I could do:
`setTimeout(function(){ ... }, 4000);`
but I would need a way to add to this timer. (i.e. The timer has 1 second left, I click on a field and I want the timer to go back to 4 seconds)

Comment: what's the problem? What do you mean by *but I would need a way to add to this timer.*

Comment: How can the user do anything while the calculation is happening? That doesn't make any sense. Unless by calculation you mean ajax request or something.

Comment: Yes, I am using AJAX to call a function in MVC. The tool attempts to request the calculation providing the that the inputs are valid on the client side.#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is something like this:

```
var isCalculating = false;
var calculateQueue = false;

function calculate(){
  isCalculating = true;

  // do calculations

  isCalculating = false;

  if(calculateQueue){
    calculate();
  }
}

$('element').blur(function(){
  if(!isCalculating){
    calculate();
  }
  else{
    calculateQueue = true;
  }
});
```

This way you don't run concurrent `calculate()` functions. No need for endless timers, and if there are calculations "queued" then they will be calculated after the first calculate function stops... rather than waiting 4s each time. What happens when you change your calculate function and it takes longer?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled by calling `clearTimeout()` before executing the `setTimeout()` to clear any pending actions.

```
// Declare the variable that holds the timeout pointer at a higher scope
var ts;

// in your onblur
// clear any pending pointer
if (ts) window.clearTimeout(ts);
// then reset the timeout and assign its handle to the same variable ts
ts = window.setTimeout(function() {}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is not to add to the timer, but to clear the previous timer.

You could do it like:

```
var delay = (function() {
    var time_id;
    return function(callback, ms) {
      if (time_id) {
         window.clearTimeout(time_id);
      }
      time_id = window.setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
}());

// use it like
delay(function(){...}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remember the timeoutID and reset the old timer each time you start a new one.

```
var timeoutID = null;
if ( timeoutID !== null ) {
  window.clearTimeout( timeoutID );
}
timeoutID  = window.setTimeout( function(){
  // your code here
}, 4000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `clearTimeout` is the way to handle this. I put together a really basic example of how this works. A click on the button will cancel and restart the timer before the function runs, but this event could easily be bound to another event (like a focus or blur on a field, like it looks like you would be doing)

[Example of delaying execution with clearTimeout here >>](http://jsfiddle.net/eW7m7/1/)